# How to deal with post-high-school gap in CV?

Tags: graduate-admissions, cv

I am currently finishing my undergraduate degree, and I am working on my CV for graduate school applications. After High School, I spent ~1.5 years traveling, mostly by myself, and with no notable employment.

Do I write this in my CV? If so, should I just mention it or say anything further about it?

Comment: Do you need to mention what you did before your undergraduate studies in your CV?

Comment: It might help to understand *what countries* you are applying to study in. The advice on this and other questions would be wrong for Japan but right for the US.

Answer (score 17):

Honestly, if I were you, I simply wouldn't list my high school dates on my CV.  Lots of applications don't, and I've never seen this be a problem or concern.  Given that you now are getting an undergraduate degree, the graduate schools won't care much about it.  I doubt anyone will pay much attention if you do write in your date of high school graduation and simply don't explain the gap, but why even bring up the topic?

**EDIT:** Just to clarify, I wasn't suggest you list your high school without dates, but that you just leave it off entirely.  I would say you definitely don't want to list it once you've entered grad school.  When applying to grad school as an undergrad, I think it's fine to leave it there, but don't expect anyone to think it's important.

Comment: I simply wouldn't list my *high school* on my CV.

Comment: +1 Every CV I've ever seen lists baccalaureate studies or higher.

Comment: I did not even finish high school and nobody seems to care since I have a variety of higher degrees.

Comment: Keep in mind that in some cultures, secondary education may be considered very important for some reason. Germany comes to mind.

Answer (score 6):

Many people take a gap year between highschool and college and between college and grad school for various reasons (walkabout, military service, family care responsibilities). Unless it's significant for either your personal growth or is notable for another reason (length of time > 5 years; etc.) there's simply no reason to mention it.